# How do i show 100% clarity element in div opacity

Tags: html, css

I have a div with opacity: 40% . But i want  the text in div show with opacity 100%

```
#box {
Background-color:#000;
Opacity:40%;
}
```

Comment: what have you tried to achieve this ? also, css properties are not capitalized. Also `opacity` doesn't have percentage values. `40%` would be `0.4`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used Background color with rgba

```css
#box {
  background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.4);
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">Text</div>
```